# Error running Bumblebee Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, bumblebee, hybrid, switchable-graphics

I'm trying to get bumblebee working because my pc has 2 graphic cards, one Intel i7 7th gen and one Nvidia GeForce 940MX. I want to use the Intel one for almost everything and the Nvidia one for gaming. I installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers from "additional drivers" in "software and updates". The driver version it installed is 390.48. I also installed the bumblebee packages from the official repositories following [this guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-install-and-configure-bumblebee.html).

When I ran the `optirun` command to work with Nvidia it gets an error.

```
[ 2028.874087] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
[ 2028.874188] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Comment: Does an integrated graphics card count as a second card?

Comment: Why would not count?

Comment: well when I had my gaming computer, I just treated it as having 2 GPUs. I just ignored the integrated Intel one.

Comment: Does this link: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/newbie-questions-about-hybrid-nvidia-and-intel-gpu-drives-tutorial/2974/9 help at all? It suggests some wiki articles.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, bumblebee doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04. You might want to follow [this useful guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CezzY3DGi4U) on how to set your Intel and Nvidia graphics to work.

Basically, after installing Nvidia drivers, use:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

and then reboot to switch to intel graphics, and

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

and reboot to switch to Nvidia graphics.